# What is the best way to predict external test set?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

My Question is theoretical rather technical, hence I am not posting my code here because code is available at sklearn website itself.

I constructed a classifier and cross-validating with 5 folds using sklearn. In my code, I am calculating various accuracy parameter like sensitivity, specificity, f1-score, etc. in each fold. After 5 fold cross-validation averaging all the accuracy parameters after the completion of the folds.

Finally, my script creates a ROC curve along with the AUC score and histogram for other accuracy parameters and generates an HTML report file.

Cross-validation means internal testing, but when I used an external test data set confusion starts.

My question is that how should I predict external data set, which is the correct amongst the bellow method.

1. After cross-validation, save the model which has averaged parameters from each and every fold and use this model to predict external test set and calculate assessment report. If this is the case how can I do this? Can you show me the example code which helps me to save a model after n fold cross-validation?
2. Build the model using the entire data set, save the model to predict the external test set and calculate the assessment report. If this is the correct way, Thank you I know the code.
3. Is there any other method that I missed, please share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach  is

> Build the model using the entire data set, save the model to predict
>   the external test set and calculate the assessment report

The reason being we use cross validation only to measure the performance of hyper parameters only. We do that by keeping the every fold as a test fold once which means every data point gets a fair chance of being as a test data point once.

Comment: Dhanyawaad.. Thank you :)